# Vue composition API - why it's not working as expected

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to debug a problem we have in [vue editor js package](https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/vue-editor-js/blob/master/src/Editor.vue) 
where everything works ok except for the "loadData" button which although it's 
changing the prop initData, the Editor component doesn't seem to render again.

I'm not a js master and this API is not clear to me, I suspect the problem is in the

`watch(_ => props.initData, _ => initEditor)`

Which looks like it's watching for initData changes but than called a function with no params ??? But i don't understand how it works (or what's the problem making it not work) ? , can anyone have a look and help debug it or say what's wrong?

Comment: "loadData" is at the demo project here https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/vue-editor-js/blob/master/demo/Demo.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call the initEditor function not just return it

for example

`watch(_ => props.initData, _ => initEditor(props))`